# &trade showing up invoices but shows as ™ in products

Tags: magento-1.9

I had a slight issue when importing where I couldn't import any products with ™ in the title and it was suggested that I import the products using `&trade;` instead. This has worked perfectly up until I realized that it's showing up in the generated invoices as `&trade;` rather than than ™.

Essentially the question is, how can I substitute `&trade;` in the invoice PDFs located at `sales->invoices->invoice->print` in the admin panel to ™?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply copying `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php`

and changing

```
'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($item->getName(), 35, true, true),
```

to

```
'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(html_entity_decode($item->getName()), 35, true, true),
```

Which solved my issue :).